# GEM Ransack - using ransack to search through a link - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm new to rails so your help and advise would be much appreciated.

- i am currently using the gem `ransack`
- in my schema i have a table called `adverts` with the columns `title` & `content`
- i am trying to create a search with ransack through a link
- i have a link called similar jobs [`<%= link_to 'similar jobs', search_adverts_path(q: {advert_title_eq: @advert.title}), class: "fa fa-plus-square" %>`]
- currently in my app when a user clicks on `similar jobs` for an advert with the title `risk analyst`, it displays search results with the exact advert title 'risk analyst' but what i would like is to display search results containing 'risk' & 'analyst' - so example, 'business analyst' 'risk analyst' 'financial analyst' etc should be displayed in the search result list, but only 'risk analyst' is being displayed

> what i want to do is:

- when a user views an advert e.g: risk analyst and clicks on the link 'similar jobs' the search should display adverts with titles containing 'risk' & 'analyst'

> adverts_controller.rb

in my adverts controller i have the below action:

```
  def search
    @userj = current_userj
    if params[:q].present? and params[:q][:advert_title_eq].present?
     params[:q][:title_cont] = params[:q][:advert_title_eq]
    end 
    @search = Advert.search(params[:q])
    @adverts = @search.result(distinct: true)
    @active_adverts = @adverts.where(['appdeadline >= ?', Time.zone.today]) #displays adverts with deadline > or = to current date
    @active_adverts_count = @active_adverts.count
  end
```

views / adverts / show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'similar jobs', search_adverts_path(q: {advert_title_eq: @advert.title}), class: "fa fa-plus-square" %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A github repo [Ransack link search](https://github.com/shreeramneupane/ransack_link_search) have the solution of similar problem.

where, the link is as:

`<%= link_to 'similar jobs', search_adverts_path(q: {title_cont_any: @advert.title.split(' ')}) %>`

and the search action is as:

`def search
    @search = Advert.search(params[:q])
    @adverts = @search.result(distinct: true)
  end`

But, if you want to solve in your way, just refactor the search action `if condition block` only as

`if params[:q].present? and params[:q][:advert_title_eq].present?
    params[:q][:title_cont_any] = params[:q][:advert_title_eq].split(' ')
 end`

Comment: IMO this answer did not add anything to mine. That I answered 2 hours before. Except it has a scaffold made with my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done at link level:

```
<%= link_to 'similar jobs', search_adverts_path(q: {advert_title_cont_any: @advert.title.split}), class: "fa fa-plus-square" %>
```

I found at [ransack wiki](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching#cont_any-contains-any). I did test it at rails console.

Also, you'll need to remove:

```
if params[:q].present? and params[:q][:advert_title_eq].present?
  params[:q][:title_cont] = params[:q][:advert_title_eq]
end
```

At your controller.